# How do I find a string in a list that matches a string or substring in another list

Tags: python

How can I find a string in List1 that is a substring of any of the strings in List2? Both lists can be of different lengths.

Say I have:

```
List1=['hello', 'hi', 'ok', 'apple']

List2=['okay', 'never', 'goodbye']
```

I need it to return 'ok', seeing as it was the only string in list1 that matched list2.

Comment: Do you want to match ok in List1 to okay in Okay

Comment: I reworded your question to be more understandable. It is not clear whether you wanted to return the first string that matches or list of all strings, please comment.

Answer (score 8):

You can use list comprehension as:

`[x for x in List1 for y in List2 if x in y]`

Comment: Yeah, its pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if a string from list1 is in list2 you can do

```
for s in List1:
    if s in List2:
        print("found s in List2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this piece of code to implement the

```
List1=['hello', 'hi', 'ok', 'apple']
List2=['ok', 'never', 'goodbye']
i=[]
for j in List1:
    for k in List2:
        if j==k:
            i.append(j)

print i
```

Comment: `if j in k` would fit better I guess